# How can I turn a part of the filename into a variable when reading multiple text files?

Tags: r

I have multiple textfiles (around 60) that I merge into a single file. I am looking for way of only adding the first 4 digits of the file name in a variable for each file. An example of a file name is `1111_2222_3333.txt`.

So basically I need an additional variable that includes the first 4 digits of the file name per file.

I did find the following related topics, but this does not allow me to include the 4 four digits only:
[How can I turn the filename into a variable when reading multiple csvs into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092102/how-can-i-turn-the-filename-into-a-variable-when-reading-multiple-csvs-into-r)

[R: Read multiple files and label them based on the file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004634/r-read-multiple-files-and-label-them-based-on-the-file-name)

My code that does not include the file name yet is currently:

```
files <- list.files("pathname", pattern="*.TXT")
masterfilesales <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files, read.table))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Although the initial answer is correct, the same goal can be achieved in fewer steps by using `sapply` with `simplify=FALSE` instead of `lapply` because `sapply` automatically assigns the filenames to the elements in the list:

```
library(data.table)

files <- list.files("pathname", pattern="*.TXT")
file.list <- sapply(files, read.table, simplify=FALSE)
masterfilesales <- rbindlist(file.list, idcol="id")[, id := substr(id,1,4)]
```

**Old answer:** To achieve what you want, you can utilize a combination of the `setattr` function and the `idcol` pararmeter of the `rbindlist` function from the `data.table`-package as follows:

```
library(data.table)

files <- list.files("pathname", pattern="*.TXT")
file.list <- lapply(files, read.table)
setattr(file.list, "names", files)
masterfilesales <- rbindlist(file.list, idcol="id")[, id := substr(id,1,4)]
```

---

Alternatively, you can set the filenames in base R with:

```
attr(file.list, "names") <- files
```

or:

```
names(file.list) <- files
```

and bind them together with `bind_rows` from the `dplyr` package (which has also an `.id` parameter to create an id-column):

```
masterfilesales <- bind_rows(file.list, .id="id") %>% mutate(id = substr(id,1,4))
```

Comment: I tried the code in the first box and it works perfectly, thanks a lot!

Comment: I am now running the same analysis with all my input files, but keep getting the following error: 

Error in rbindlist(file.list, idcol = "id") : 
  unused argument (idcol = "id")

I have 2 differences compared to before: (1) I am running this on a server, but it works to upload the files without extracting a part of the file name and (2) I run this on all my files (n=642). Not all file names are unique. 

Anyone an idea what I do wrong?

Comment: @research111 Which version of `data.table` do you have? You need 1.9.6 (or higher) for the `idcol` argument.

Comment: 1.9.4. It seems that on the server I by default installed this version while on my desktop 1.9.6.

I downloaded 1.9.6 and it works again. Very helpful, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
c("1111_444.txt", "443343iqueh.txt") -> a

substring(a, first=1, last=4)
```