# R: How to add multiple variables at the end of a data frame from the file name

Tags: r

Apologies if this is a trivial question. I saw others like it such as: [How can I turn a part of the filename into a variable when reading multiple text files into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313895/how-can-i-turn-a-part-of-the-filename-into-a-variable-when-reading-multiple-text) , but I still seem to be having some trouble...

I have been given 50000 .txt files. Each file contains a single observation (a single row of data) with exactly 12 variables (number of columns). The name of each .txt file is fairly regular. Specifically, each .txt file has a code at the end indicating the type of observation across three dimensions. An example of this code is 'VL-VL-NE' or 'VL-M-N' or 'H-H-L' (not including the apostrophes). Therefore, an example of a file name could be 'I-love-using-R-20_01_2016-VL-VL-NE.txt'.

My problem is that I want to include this code at the end of the .txt file in the actual vector itself when I import into R, i.e., I want to add three more variables (columns) at the end of the table corresponding to the three parts of code at the end of the file name.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you have some code that imports the text files? If you have this it should be a simple `regex` to get the codes from the filename

Answer (score 0):

Because you have exactly the same number of columns in each file, why don't you import them into R using a loop that looks for all .txt files in a particularly directory?

```
df <- c()
for (x in list.files(pattern="*.txt")) {
  u<-read.csv(x, skip=6)
  u$Label = factor(x) #A column that is the filename
  df <- rbind(df,u)
}
```

You'll note that the file name itself becomes a column. Once everything is into R, it should be fairly easy to use a `regex` function to extract the exact elements you need from the file name column (`df$Label`).

Comment: If your `df` gets sufficiently big, you will run into performance issues. If the number of rows is known beforehand as in this case, it would be better to preallocate, i.e. create an empty`df` with the required dimensions.

Comment: I don't disagree but I'm not sure of an equivalent method to accomplish this.

Comment: It should be quite simple. so the number of rows of the data.frame will be `length(list.files(pattern="*.txt"))` and the number of columns will be whatever the number of columns there should be. then you can do something like `as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = number of cols, nrow = number of rows))`

Comment: and then you fill in the `df` by row index